# How to parse xml strings by using multiple namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, namespaces, deserialization

I am trying to parse a set of xml strings with various distinct response types. I created different namespaces for each response and defined the classes in order to deserialize the xml string.

```
namespace MyManager.ResponseA
{
    public class Envelope
    {
        ...
        // some children for A
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace MyManager.ResponseB
{
    public class Envelope
    {
        ...
        // some different children for B
        ...
    }
}
```

and so on. The reason I did this is that I have multiple different responses, but all start with a surrounding Envelope, which I use as the source of my xml parsing. The child objects are different though.

Say I want to write a deserializer for these classes. Is there a way to use a namespace as a generic type or to accomplish something different?

This is my intention, but obviously this doesn't work. I want to use my namespace as a generic type T:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string key)
    {
        T.Envelope envelope = null;
        StringReader stringReader = null;
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = null;
        XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = null;
        try
        {
            stringReader = new StringReader(response);
            xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T.Envelope));
            xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
            envelope = (T.Envelope)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.Write(exp.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xmlTextReader != null)
            {
                xmlTextReader.Close();
            }
            if (stringReader != null)
            {
                stringReader.Close();
            }
        }
        return T;
    }
```

So my question is: How would I do this member lookup by defining the appropriate namespace? Is my whole architecture flawed? (I think so)
What would be an appropriate practice to parse xml files which are predictable but of varying shape? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have any say in the solution, I'd recommend that you use JSON rather than XML.

Comment: I have no control over the api from which I get the xml responses

Comment: Ah, you might want to re-word your questions then. Sounds like you wanted to create a REST API.

Comment: I do want to create a REST API